# How to find XGBoost containers for different regions in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to follow AWS Sagemaker tutorial to train a machine learning model with a Jupyter notebook environment.

According to the tutorial, I'm supposed to copy the following code and run it to import required libraries and set environment variables.

```py
# import libraries
import boto3, re, sys, math, json, os, sagemaker, urllib.request
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import numpy as np                                
import pandas as pd                               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                   
from IPython.display import Image                 
from IPython.display import display               
from time import gmtime, strftime                 
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer   

# Define IAM role
role = get_execution_role()
prefix = 'sagemaker/DEMO-xgboost-dm'
containers = {'us-west-2': '433757028032.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-1': '811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-2': '825641698319.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'} # each region has its XGBoost container
my_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name # set the region of the instance
print("Success - the MySageMakerInstance is in the " + my_region + " region. You will use the " + containers[my_region] + " container for your SageMaker endpoint.")
```

And the expected outcome is below.

[image]

However, I am getting this error.

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        18               'eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'} # each region has its XGBoost container
>        19 my_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name # set the region of the instance
>   ---> 20 print("Success - the MySageMakerInstance is in the " + my_region + " region. You will use the " + containers[my_region] + " container for your SageMaker endpoint.")
>
> KeyError: 'ap-northeast-2'

I assume that this is happening because my region is **"ap-northeast-2"**. 
I have a feeling that I need to change the containers for my region.

**If my guess is correct, how can I find containers for my region?**
**Also, am I overlooking anything else?**

Comment: For the container by region mapping, see ritika's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your rational is correct. There isn't an entry for your region in the code. I don't know if there's a list of these containers per region. That being said, you find them in ECR (Elastic Container Registry).

Keep in mind, that you can probably fix this quickly by switching to one of the supported regions. Otherwise:

If AWS doesn't have a publicly listed container in your region, you can register the container yourself in AWS with ECR. You'll need to login to ECR using the AWS CLI and docker login.

You can use the command `aws ecr get-login --region ap-northeast-2` in order to get the token you'll need for docker login.

Then, clone this repo: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container

You can build this image locally and push it up to ECR. After that, login to the AWS console (or use the AWS CLI) and find the ARN of the image. It should match the format of the others in your code.

After that, just add another key/value entry into the code for your `containers` variable and use `'ap-northeast-2': '<ARN of the docker image>'`

Answer (score 3):

Find your Training Image and Inference Image Registry Path in XGBoost (0.72) at this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html

In your case it will be 'ap-northeast-2'.Add it to your container with relevant ecr.It should work fine.